# Mistakenly made a branch from another one instead of the main line

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I am new to git and accidentally created new branch from another branch instead of `main`.

My current map:

```
           f-g
          /
       d-e
      /
 a-b-c
```

`f` and `g` should be coming from main

```
        d-e
      /
 a-b-c
      \
       f-g
```

I need to move `f` and `g` to a new branch coming from main.
Note: I already pushed them to GitHub

Comment: Try reseting the the branch pointing to `g` back to `c` and then cherry picking `f` and `g`?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: I need to move f and g to new branch coming that from main

Answer (score 1):

You can move the branch to start from `c` using [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

Assuming your current branch points to commit `g` **make sure your working tree is clean** (run `git status` to find out).

Create a backup branch that points to `g` (run `git branch backup`). It can be used to restore the original position of the current branch if you are not pleased with the result. You can remove it (`git branch -D backup`) at the end.

To move the commits run:

```
git rebase --onto c HEAD~2
```

This command cuts the commits that are reachable from the current branch and are not reachable from `HEAD~2` and replays them on top of commit `c`.

Replace `2` with the exact number of commits you want to move.

If the `git rebase` operation fails (due to conflicts) run `git rebase --abort` to restore the branch to its original position (on commit `g`).